# Translate php curl to node js request

Tags: php, node.js, curl, request

I have the following php code:

```
        //Create url
        $url = "https://pci.zcredit.co.il/WebControl/RequestToken.aspx";
        $post = "TerminalNumber=$TerminalNumber"
        ."&Username=$UserName&PaymentSum=$PaymentSum&PaymentsNumber=$PaymentsNumber&Lang=$Lang"
        ."&Currency=$Currency&UniqueID=$UniqueID&ItemDescription=$ItemDescription&ItemQtty=$ItemQtty"
        ."&ItemPicture=$ItemPicture&RedirectLink=$RedirectLink&NotifyLink=$NotifyLink"
        ."&UsePaymentsRange=$UsePaymentsRange&ShowHolderID=$ShowHolderID&AuthorizeOnly=$AuthorizeOnly"
        ."&HideCustomer=$HideCustomer&CustomerName=$CustomerName&CssType=$CssType&IsCssResponsive=$IsCssResponsive";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Create the request url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); //Set post value
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Set the request method to POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Not return data in brower
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $page = curl_exec($ch);    // Get the response
```

Which I'm trying to use in node js, with Request:

```
let url = "https://pci.zcredit.co.il/WebControl/RequestToken.aspx";
        let post = `TerminalNumber=${TerminalNumber}`
        +`&Username=${UserName}&PaymentSum=${PaymentSum}&PaymentsNumber=${PaymentsNumber}&Lang=${Lang}`
        +`&Currency=${Currency}&UniqueID=${UniqueID}&ItemDescription=${ItemDescription}&ItemQtty=${ItemQtty}`
        +`&ItemPicture=${ItemPicture}&RedirectLink=${RedirectLink}&NotifyLink=${NotifyLink}`
        +`&UsePaymentsRange=${UsePaymentsRange}&ShowHolderID=${ShowHolderID}&AuthorizeOnly=${AuthorizeOnly}`
        +`&HideCustomer=${HideCustomer}&CustomerName=${CustomerName}&CssType=${CssType}&IsCssResponsive=${IsCssResponsive}`;

const request = require('request');

request(url +'/' + post, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }

});
```

But should I just add the post parameters to the original url? Is it secure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its as secure as the php example but adding the parameters to the URL would be a GET request. If you want a "real" post request you should add the params to the request body. Anyway concerning security you could check the values of the params. Maybe they could include malicious code. The Server should check that anyway but you can do a lot of sanitizing and checking in your code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for posting URL-encoded forms with [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms) is simple as:

```
request.post(url).form({ key: value })
```

Of course, you can choose to send the request with the parameters in the url, using template literals variables, and that will change nothing in a security point of view, but it will be more readable.

Your code will be secure if you sanitize the parameters and if you use encryption (https), the same way you should do in any language, as *main.c* says in his comment.